# check against empty form field

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java so bear with me. I've got a simple script that processes form data and sends it to the error log. I've got a simple null check that is suppose to say if the phone field isn't filled in don't send it to the error log. But for some reason it's not working. So what I'm getting in the error log is simply the string "Phone number associated with account:" any ideas?

```
String phone = request.getParameter("phoneNumber");
String showPhone = (phone != null) ? " Phone number associated with account: " + phone : "";

log.error(showPhone);
```

Comment: Looks like `phone` is an empty String...

Comment: No clue what the "form data" is, but if it's from a web app, an empty text field is empty, not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what framework you're using, but a null object and an empty string are not the same in Java. You might want to try:

```
String showPhone = (phone != null && phone.trim().length()>0) ? " Phone number associated with account: " + phone : "";
```

The `&& phone.trim().length()>0` is the ensure that the string has content.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to use is [`StringUtils.isNotEmpty`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNotEmpty%28java.lang.String%29)

```
 StringUtils.isNotEmpty(null)      = false
 StringUtils.isNotEmpty("")        = false
 StringUtils.isNotEmpty(" ")       = true
 StringUtils.isNotEmpty("bob")     = true
 StringUtils.isNotEmpty("  bob  ") = true
```

Or [`StringUtils.isNotBlank`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank%28java.lang.String%29)

```
 StringUtils.isNotBlank(null)      = false
 StringUtils.isNotBlank("")        = false
 StringUtils.isNotBlank(" ")       = false
 StringUtils.isNotBlank("bob")     = true
 StringUtils.isNotBlank("  bob  ") = true
```

Like this:

```
String phone = request.getParameter("phoneNumber");
String showPhone = StringUtils.isNotBlank(phone) ? " Phone number associated with account: " + phone : "";
```

Comment: +1, though it should be noted that StringUtils is part of Apache commons-lang, and is not a part of standard JavaSE libraries. Not usually a problem, unless you're running in an environment where 3rd-party libraries are controlled/restricted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool isNullOrEmpty(String val){
return val==null||"".val.trim();
}
```